# I've been / I've kept / I keep running?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, usage

I want to express that I've been running for a while and I'm still running at the moment.

I know I can use *I've been running for a while*. If I want to use *keep*, should I say *I've kept running for a while*, *I keep running for a while*, or something else?

Comment: Why do you want to use *keep*? It doesn't work the same way as *to be*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I have been running for a while", as you know implies you're still running now.

*Keep* in this context is synonymous with *continue*. It's quite difficult to use these in the same manner as *be*.

"I have kept running for a while" doesn't make sense. You can't use *have kept* to describe a continuing action.

"I keep running for a while" would be used if you were describing the event afterwards, but using the present tense. For example "I set off north at a good pace. I keep running for a while until I reach a cliff."

If you want to use *keep* to describe a current and ongoing action, you'll need to make a much more complicated sentence.

The closest I can think of is:

> I have kept up my running for a while.

Which isn't right, because it talks about habit, rather than a current action.

A rather unpleasant way to phrase it:

> I'm still keeping going with my run.

The *still* doesn't really mean "for a while" but it does imply some kind of stamina.

In conclusion, I wouldn't use *keep*, in this context, if I could avoid it.